# What is the characteristic function of the devil’s staircase?

Tags: pr.probability

Let the distribution function $CDF(X,t)$ of a random variable $X$ be defined as $0$  for $ t <0, \text{Cantor function}(t)$ for $t \ge 0$ and $ t \le 1, 1$ for $ t > 1$ (for example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function for the used definition). What is the characteristic function of $X$? It would be an example of the characteristic function of a singular distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be a comment but I'm 9 points short.

The answer's  on wikepedia.
It's $e^{\tfrac{it}2} \prod_{i=1}^\infty cos\left(\frac t{3i}\right)$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution

I'm pretty sure there's no closed form of the infinite product.

Comment: Can you kindly give a reference for the proof?

Comment: There's also a reference on the wikipedia page.
http://www.calpoly.edu/~kmorriso/Research/RandomWalks.pdf

The proof is on page 4.